# Creating custom image filter for flutter application

Tags: flutter, imagefilter

I kind of reverse engineered an image filter. Actually it was just a pixel by pixel operation so I applied it over different images and by comparing each pixel of original image and filtered image (using PIL) I now know what RGB value from original image became what RGB in the filtered image. For example like RGB(0,0,1) became RGB(2,3,81) (suppose) etc and I know this for all 16,777,216 colors.

If what I did is correct then my question is how can I create a filter out of this data that can be used in flutter apps. One option is to use conditional statements but that's just theoretical as I'll have to manually write 16,777,216 statements just for this one filter. So is there any software or program or code or anything else that I can use to create a filter out of this data **that can be used in flutter apps.** This is important because ultimately I want to use this filter in my flutter app.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you very much.